# Python : Compare two files

Tags: python

I have two input file:

scandinavian    t   airline airline
one n   0   flightnumber
six n   0   flightnumber
two n   0   flightnumber
three   n   0   flightnumber

speedbird   t   airline airline
one n   0   flightnumber
six n   0   flightnumber
eight   n   0   flightnumber

My second input file:

scandinavian    t   airline airli
one n   0   flightnumber
six n   0   flightnumber
two n   0   flightnumber
three   n   0   flightnumber

six n   0   flightnumber
eight   n   0   flightnumber

I have the following code:

```
with open('output_ref.txt', 'r') as file1:
with open('output_ref1.txt', 'r') as file2:
same = set(file1).difference(file2)
print same
print "\n"

same.discard('\n')

with open('some_output_file.txt', 'w') as FO:
for line in same:
    FO.write(line)
```

And I am getting output as:

scandinavian    t   airline airline
speedbird   t   airline airline

But my actual output should be:

scandinavian    t   airline airline
speedbird   t   airline airline
one n   0   flightnumber

Can someone help me in solving the issue??

Comment: Set is unique. So you have only one "one n 0 flightnumber" line after doing 'set(file1)'. Maybe you would prefer a list?

Comment: Python has a builtin difflib (as an aside since it doesn't answer the question that was asked).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def diff(a, b):
    y = []
    for x in a:
        if x not in b:
            y.append(x)
        else:
            b.remove(x)
    return y

with open('output_ref.txt', 'r') as file1:
    with open('output_ref1.txt', 'r') as file2:
        same = diff(list(file1), list(file2))
        print same
        print "\n"

if '\n' in same:
    same.remove('\n')

with open('some_output_file.txt', 'w') as FO:
    for line in same:
        FO.write(line)
```

```bsh
$ python compare.py
['scandinavian t airline airline\n', 'speedbird t airline airline\n', 'one n 0 flightnumber\n']



$ cat some_output_file.txt 
scandinavian t airline airline
speedbird t airline airline
one n 0 flightnumber
```

Comment: Welcome :-) I wonder why someone would down vote an answer after being accepted by the op.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if what you are trying to do is get the common lines from 2 file (which the "same" variable name suggests) , then you should use the intersection method instead of difference . Also , both these methods are stated to require sets as their arguments so i would go the extra step and turn the second file into a set too . So the new code should be:

```
 first = set(file1)
 second = set(file2)
 same = first.intersection(second)
```

.....

EDIT :

reading some comments to my post convinced me that you actually want the difference and not on sets, but on lists . I guess this should work for you :

```
difference = list(file1)
second = list(file2)
for line in second:
    try:
        first.remove(line)
    except ValueError,e:
        print e # alternately you could just pass here
```

Comment: No, this is not the solution to his problem. As @cyrille-pontvieux says, it fails because set eliminate duplicates and `one n 0 flightnumber` appears in both set objects.

Comment: speedbird t airline airline is only present in the first file. Besides, if what he wants is not the common lines then i guess naming the variable "same" is a really bad idea

Comment: of course, I agree with you in that naming `same` the variable is confusing, but from his expected output and his code I guess he wants to get the differences